# Как присвоить значение href URL() в фронтенде если сайт Многоязычый?

Tags: php, laravel

Использую Laravel,  сайт должен быть на трех языках ru, en, fr.

Как присвоить значение в фронтенде, нужно ли все время использоать app()->getLocal() например  (`<a href="{{ URL(app()->getLocal().'/about' }} >)` ?

Как правильно настроить Route  файл для таких запросов ?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [route prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-prefixes).

Вот простой пример префикса с использованием [Laravel-localizations](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#usage)

```
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
],
function () {
    Route::get('/{slug}', function () {
        return view('pages');
    })->name('pages.show');
});
```

на выходе получим `/ru/page-slug`